# Scripted expression: Can I even include &&s? If else and special conditions

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I'm attempting my luck with scripted expressions today, and my specific situation is about using &&s as following:

```
-((((rotation_euler_l*2.9375)+(rotation_euler_r*2.9375))/2)+0.35) if(((rotation_euler_l+rotation_euler_r)/2)<=-0.025 && -(rotation_euler_l+rotation_euler_r)<=0) else -((((rotation_euler_l*2.9375)+(rotation_euler_r*2.9375))/2))
```

Which, oh wonders is not working. ("ERROR: Invalid Python expression") I am assuming that I might also have misplaced a bracket - but in case I did not -

Q: Is Blender able to read the "&&" expression common in languages like C# where you write things like

```
if ((left+right)/2 == 0 && left+right <=0 ) {do something;} else {do this instead;}
```

?

My code is working if I remove the && condition from the if bracket:

```
-((((rotation_euler_l*2.9375)+(rotation_euler_r*2.9375))/2)+0.35) if(((rotation_euler_l+rotation_euler_r)/2)<=-0.025) else -((((rotation_euler_l*2.9375)+(rotation_euler_r*2.9375))/2))
```

Where did I go wrong? Hope somebody can explain why the uppermost code sample is throwing me an error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a python question, not a specific Blender one! Use 'and' instead of '&&'. (Without the quotes.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485466/what-is-pythons-equivalent-of-logical-and-in-an-if-statement

Comment: Thank you kindly for letting me know. I never properly learnt python so I am prone to errors. Thought Blender does not do "&&"/"and"s, after googling the issue led me to no related question - didn't assume python uses "and" instead of "&&". Your suggestion worked, wanted to let you know.

Comment: Good to hear! it's a long time since I used python myself so I had to look it up and check. Blender uses standard python notation so if it's wrong in native python, it's wrong in blender! :^)